# Parsing a double from a string which holds a value greater than Double.MaxValue

Tags: java, parsing, double, ieee-754

Consider the following java code:

```
String toParse = "1.7976931348623157E308"; //max value of a double in java        
double parsed = Double.parseDouble(toParse);
System.out.println(parsed);
```

For the mentioned value of `1.7976931348623157E308` everything makes sense and one gets the correct output.

Now, if one tries to parse `1.7976931348623158E308` (last digit before `E` incremented) you still get the maximum value printed into the console!
Only after trying to parse `1.7976931348623159E308` (again the last digit got incremented) and greater one gets `Infinity`.
Same behaviour for the corresponding negative values.

Why is `... 8E308` parsed to `... 7E308` and not `Infinity`?

Comment: Has this any relevance for any application?

Comment: I guess that you're having fun with edge cases. Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @AlexWien just stumbled upon this by "accident", now I'm curious

Comment: @BastiM: compare the binary representation of your decimal values to the binary values specified in the API.

Comment: @basti you will loose your curiouseness when you look at that code, i have looked at it. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SE 7 version of the parseDouble documentation refers to the valueOf documentation which says:

> Note that the round-to-nearest rule also implies overflow and underflow behaviour; if the exact value of s is large enough in magnitude (greater than or equal to (MAX_VALUE + ulp(MAX_VALUE)/2), rounding to double will result in an infinity and if the exact value of s is small enough in magnitude (less than or equal to MIN_VALUE/2), rounding to float will result in a zero.

This is consistent with the statement that the rounding to type double is by the usual round-to-nearest rule of IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic.

You have to imagine the conversion being done by first calculating the nearest floating point number ignoring the exponent limitation, and then checking whether the exponent fits. Double.MAX_VALUE is the closest number under that rule to some numbers that are strictly greater than it.

To confirm this is normal rounding behavior, consider the following program:

```
    public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        double ulp = Math.ulp(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(ulp);
        System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE+ulp/2.0000000001);
        System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE+ulp/2);
      }
    }
```

It outputs:

```
1.9958403095347198E292
1.7976931348623157E308
1.7976931348623157E308
Infinity
```

Adding something even slightly less than half a ulp to Double.MAX_VALUE does not change it. Adding half a ulp overflows to infinity.

Comment: +1 for the example code, this was the part which wrapped my head around it! thanks, patricia