# Incrementing MAX_VALUE of primitve type

Tags: java, max, increment

I try to understand the following code:

```java
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;

System.out.println(i + ":" + (i+1));
System.out.println(d + ":" + (d+1));
```

The output is:

```
2147483647:-2147483648
1.7976931348623157E308:1.7976931348623157E308
```

For the first line, `i` is equal to the maximum integer and incrementing it leads to the lowest integer value. Why the same is not happening with `d`?

Is there a simple explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537757/parsing-a-double-from-a-string-which-holds-a-value-greater-than-double-maxvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer overflows because it is represented in a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format.

- `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is represented by `0111...111`
- `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is represented by `1000...000`

So when you try and add 1 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, according to the normal rules of addition, you get `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. This is called overflow.

Floating point numbers have a different representation, which doesn't lend itself to this type of overflow. They are all approximations, and the closest approximation it has to the value you gave it is `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

When a double overflows, its value becomes `Infinity`, not a negative number.

The reason why you can't overflow by simply adding 1 to `Double.MAX_VALUE` is that `MAX_VALUE + 1 == MAX_VALUE` because the precision of doubles is not enough to make the difference between those two numbers.

Actually you can add quite a large number before jumping to the next available double. For example that does not overflow either:

```
System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE + 1e100); //still Double.MAX_VALUE
```

This overflows as expected:

```
System.out.println(m + (Math.ulp(m) / 2)); //Infinity
```

Comment: Thanks for the precisions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `double` cannot represent the actual number you're trying to represent due to lose of accuracy with `double`s. That's why the value is not changing and you're actually *don't* have an overflow.

For non-`int` types, overflow will result in *Infinity*. Try to multiply that value with 20, for example, and you'll see the overflow in action.