# Invalid String to Double conversion for Double max value

Tags: scala

I am converting a string value to a Double.

Double.MaxValue is 1.7976931348623157E308

If I attempt to convert a value larger than this to a Double I would expect the converted value to be Infinity

e.g.

```
var x = "1.7976931348623158E308".toDouble
println("x: " + x)
```

I was expecting to see the following:

```
x: Inifinity
```

Instead I get

```
x: 1.7976931348623157E308
```

i.e. it converts to the MaxValue (1.7976931348623157E308)

**Scala Version:** 2.12.8

Has anyine see this behaviour ? Is it expected ?

Thanks,

Eoin.

Comment: `toDouble` wraps `java.lang.Double.valueOf()`, for which this is an expected behavior (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537757/parsing-a-double-from-a-string-which-holds-a-value-greater-than-double-maxvalue/13537890#13537890)

Comment: Yeah makes sense @sachav thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is expected behavior. Parsing of `double` value from the decimal string representation [has a rounding operation](https://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-to-floating-point-needs-arbitrary-precision/).

So, all these strings are parsed to the same value of `double`:

```
scala> java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits("1.7976931348623158079372E308".toDouble).toBinaryString
res0: String = 111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

scala> java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits("1.7976931348623158E308".toDouble).toBinaryString
res1: String = 111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

scala> java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits("1.7976931348623157123641238313346568234E308".toDouble).toBinaryString
res2: String = 111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

scala> java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits("1.7976931348623157E308".toDouble).toBinaryString
res3: String = 111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

scala> java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits("1.79769313486231567E308".toDouble).toBinaryString
res4: String = 111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: Thanks @Andriy Plokhotnyuk